# How do I agree to install the package?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

My playbook:

```yaml
    - name: "install software"
      hosts: local
      connection: local
    
      tasks:
        - name: install git
          expect:
            command: yum install git
            responses:
              Is this ok [y/d/N]: 'y'
```

I execute the command `sudo ansible-playbook test.yaml`, but I get an error.

```
Total download size: 4.5 M                                                                               
Installed size: 22 M                            
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

MSG:

`non-zero return code`

Comment: Instead of using the `yum` command, try using the [yum module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/yum_module.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to avoid the expect module entirely and use the `yum` module instead

```
- name: Install git
  yum:
    name: git
    state: latest
```

This way, it will autoaccept

---

For expect module maybe you could try this.

```
responses:
  (.*)Is this ok(.*): 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Whereby the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71615015/6771046) **is the preferred and recommend solution**, the command line parameter to agree on installation is according `man yum`

> ```
>    -y, --assumeyes
>          Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked is yes.
>          Configuration Option: assumeyes
> ```

Therefore the task would be

```yaml
- name: Install Git via 'yum'
  shell:
    cmd: yum --assumeyes install git
    warn: false
  register: result
```

**Further Q&A**

- [How to yum install always answering yes in the y/n questions?](https://superuser.com/questions/1340315/)
- [Can I automate y/N responses while installing with yum?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109334/)